# How to make a screenshot with a Mac keyboard on a Mac that is running Windows 7?

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp, print-screen

I have a Mac that is running Windows 7 through Bootcamp. I am using an external Mac keyboard and I want to take a screenshot but I have not had any success. I tried to Google the soltuion, but all the answers that I found said to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F13</kbd>.

So, what is the solution?

If at all possbile, I don't want to resort to installing additional programs.

Comment: Are you sure there's a `F13` button? ;)

Comment: Yes, why not?   .

Comment: As it turns out, my ignorance got the better of me. Oops.

Comment: @Jin - I am not an Apple guy, but I'm under the impression a standard Mac keyboard has 15 function keys.

Comment: @Shinrai Yeah, figured that out with a bit of googling. Learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 7):

Create a keyboard shortcut with the built-in snipping tool.

`Start > Accessories > Snipping Tool > Properties > Shortcut`

[image]

Click in the `Shortcut key` text box and enter your desired key combination.

Comment: I want to make a screenshot while my mousepointer is hovering over something. This solution just starts the snippingtool and you need you mouse to select the snippet to copy.
So this is not going to work for me. All I want is just make a screenshot of the entire screen without using bootcamp or whatever.
I use a normal PC with a Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 has a built in screenshot software, [its called Snipping Tool.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool)

It can be found on the All Programs > Accessories menu

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for fullscreen

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>F11</kbd> for active window

Comment: This won't work if you've changed the 'fn' keys to work as standard F keys by default.

Answer (score 2):

Screengrab means to capture any moment you want on your screen. Snipping Tool is not well  designed for that purpose. Always be prepared for an alternative when using Microsoft made applications.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for fullscreen

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Option (Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for active window

above hotkeys indeed solve the problem, thanks to Sergiy

Answer (score 0):

GreenShot is a program (similar to SnagIt) where you're able to specify what keystroke to capture the image. You can also do selections as well as the whole screen.

http://getgreenshot.org/

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid installing additional programs if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Boot Camp Control Panel, select the Keyboard tab and uncheck the option for "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

Then the following hotkeys will work:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> for fullscreen

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>F11</kbd> for active window